# The Equals Function does not Work When it is In While Loop

Tags: java

I have code that is supposed to guess the user's number and it will narrow its search based on user input.  The only issue is that within the while loop, the conditionals are not working with .equals.  Instead, it skips to the else even when I type "less than".  This is my code below, I am new to java so I might have made a mistake.

```
package reversedHiLo;
//Import utility
import java.util.*;

public class ReversedHiLo 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //create scanner class
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to reverse number guessing game, pick a number between 1 and 100 and type it below:");
        int answer = sc.nextInt();
        //Create the first guess
        int guess = 1 + (int)(100*Math.random());
        //Create an array that stores the range of the player's number
        int[] range = new int[] {1,100};
        //While loop that guesses the number
        while(guess != answer)
        {
            System.out.println("Is your number greater than or less than " + guess + "?" + Arrays.toString(range));
            String response = sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();
            //Conditionals to set the range of the guess
            if(response.equals("less than"))
            {
                range[1] = guess;
            }
            else
            {
                range[0] = guess;
            }
            //Guess a new number based on the range
            guess = range[0] + (int)((range[1] - range[0]) * Math.random());            
        }

        //Final print
        System.out.println("Your number was " + answer + ".\nThe computer's guess was: " + guess);
        //Close scanner
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing you can, and should, figure out by using the debugger built into your IDE. Using the debugger is **not** an advanced skill; quite the opposite, after you've written your first "Hello, Java" program, learning to use the debugger should be your next task, so you can step through code, see exactly what's in your variables at a given moment in time, etc.

Comment: Re my note about the debugger above: That's not meant to be "so you shouldn't have asked this question." Just advice for moving forward with your programming education. Happy coding!

Comment: `Scanner.next()` returns the next token from the input stream, which is by default a sequence of characters up till the next whitespace characters. It will never return "less than" - "less than" is two tokens!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `Scanner.next()` ignores leading white space - including the newline after the number

Comment: @ThomasKläger - My bad, I thought there were two problems (whitespace after `nextInt`, and `next` only returning `"less"`), but when I tested locally I messed something up and mistakenly thought `next` was returning `"less than"` (which surprised me). But I just screwed up the test. Reopened, but presumably there's a duplicate for `next` returning just `"less"` (since the docs say the default delimiter is whitespace)?

Comment: Command line applications usually have to be design to allow single letter answers ie: Yes: y No: n, in this case to avoid this issue caused by multiple words and blank spaces he should just do for: less than: type letter L and for greater than type letter G etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places where there is a problem:

- The first one **sc.nextInt()** method - which only reads the int
  value by keeps current reading buffer on the same line. So to
  ignore/skip everything what is after **int** on the input line (which is
  probably \n or \r\n if you only enter the number) you have to
  use **sc.nextLine()**.
- The second one is **sc.next()** method - which
  only reads first token(or simply word) from your line. That is
  probably why you only get **"less"** value assigned to **response**
  and that will never be **.equals** to **"less than"**. So you will
  have to replace **sc.next()** one with **sc.nextLine()** and remove
  unnecessary **sc.nextLine()** from the next line.

Hope this should be clear now and you have a better understanding of what happens when you call these function. If not then I strongly advise you to have a look into Scanner class, read [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) on write multiple tests around it to get a better understanding of what is going on.

If my explanation is still not clear have a look at the code I have modified for you below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //create scanner class
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to reverse number guessing game, pick a number between 1 and 100 and type it below:");
    int answer = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();   // This one is necessary to ignore everything on the same line as your number was typed in
    //Create the first guess
    int guess = 1 + (int)(100*Math.random());
    //Create an array that stores the range of the player's number
    int[] range = new int[] {1,100};
    //While loop that guesses the number
    while(guess != answer)
    {

        System.out.println("Is your number greater than or less than " + guess + "?" + Arrays.toString(range));
        String response = sc.nextLine();  // This reads the whole input line

        //Conditionals to set the range of the guess
        if(response.equals("less than"))
        {
            range[1] = guess;
        }
        else
        {
            range[0] = guess;
        }
        //Guess a new number based on the range
        guess = range[0] + (int)((range[1] - range[0]) * Math.random());
    }

    //Final print
    System.out.println("Your number was " + answer + ".\nThe computer's guess was: " + guess);
    //Close scanner
    sc.close();
}
```